# Rails view and controllers, (if/else statements)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view-helpers, statements

I've just started my own rails project from scratch. I'm trying the view to display hello if the minutes variable is set to a certain value.

[The code](https://gist.github.com/2842923) is in the controller right now, and I want it to display the output in the view. is this possible? or do I write it in the view? Not sure of doing it right.

**home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @minutes = 23
    @minutes = params[:minutes]
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% if @minutes == 23 %>
  <%= "helllo" %>
<% else %>
  Anonymous
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think, nobody understands what are you asking for.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, I've edited your question with the code from the gist and added your doubt (taken from the gist) about how to do this the right way which probably is your question about.

Comment: need one more vote to approve the edit (new SO feature?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@minutes = params[:minutes] || 23
```

Answer (score 2):

It's good enought in this simple case put some logic in the view but usually is better to add helper methods (Read the [Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#view-helpers) guide is a good idea).

Probably you've already seen the app/helpers directory, in these helper files you can define methods which are available in the view layer, methods related to view layer but do stuff that would be weird or dirty to put in templates files.

For example in your case you could have a `/app/helpers/time_helper.rb`:

```
module TimeHelper
  # I know the method name sucks a little
  def show_hello_if_minutes_is_23(minutes = @minutes)
    if minutes==23
      "Hello"
    else
      "Anonymous"
    end
  end
end
```

and then use in your `index.html.erb` template:

```
<%= show_hello_if_minutes_is_23 %>
```

As you can see:

1. You can read the method name and understand what it does (at high level)
2. Logic is put in a ruby method
3. The method take a `minutes` argument but it's optional

And remember: usually repetition is evil (The DRY thing) but **in view-land sometimes one time is too much** (not in this simple case however).

**UPDATE**: I've just seen you put set the `@minutes` variable to 23 and then you overwrite it making the previous assignment useless. I don't know what you're trying to do in your controller but if your question is about having a default value for the minutes variable go with the [Yuri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10833920/455642) and use use the `||=` operator: `@minutes ||= params[:minutes]`.

Comment: Hey, yeah i think i was just getting a little confused with the variable etc, your helper method seems to be what im looking for. How would i display this in a view? would it be something like <% show_hello_if_minutes_is_23 %> or <% TimeHelper %>

Comment: Sorry I fixed the answer markup and now you can see how to use an helper in the view: <%= show_hello_if_minutes_is_23 %>, pay attention at the equal sign, it means the output must be placed in the template.